# How to install whois python module in windows

Tags: python

I want to install whois python module in windows.
i tried to install whois module using command

```
python setup.py install
```

downlaoded from

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pythonwhois
```

but when i try to import whois module it gives error

```
>>> import whois

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import whois
ImportError: No module named whois
```

thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you should install pip first.
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/
OR
[How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

After that go to command prompt and simply type:
    `pip install whois`

This should do it.

**Update: Alternate way to install whois?**

**Step 1:** After installing pyhton, add the following to the PATH in the Environmental Variables.

```
C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\
```

**Step 2:** Download [ez_setup.py](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py). Run it and it will install Setuptools.

**Step 3:** Go to `command line/powershell` and type:

```
easy_install whois
```

**Step 4:** You are done! Go to python and `import whois`

Comment: Be aware that that installs the `whois` module (which is not maintained, and seems incomplete), rather than the `pythonwhois` module. Disclaimer: I'm the author of `pythonwhois`.

Answer (score 1):

try using pip - http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html, download the file, run the script and then you can do like this - http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dns/using-pywhois, pip install python-whois.